# "undefined named operand" error in C assembly

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gnu, inline-assembly

I'm trying to create a function using assembly like so :

```
void asm_loop ( int n ){
    
 register int *p1 asm ("r2") = &n;
 
    asm goto (
    " cmp r2 , #0 \n\t" // Compare n to "0"
    " beq %l[ stop]" // Abort if n=0
    : 
    : [ num_repeats ] "r" ( p1 )
    : 
    :stop);
stop: 
    return ;

}
```

I have the following error and don't understand why :

```
error: undefined named operand ' stop '
```

I use gcc version upper than 4.5 so "asm goto" is included.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? As it's a label i don't understand how i can define it.

Thank you in advance.

I tried searching for more information on https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm.

But they seem to use this function the same way as I do :

```
int frob(int x)
{
  int y;
  asm goto ("frob %%r5, %1; jc %l[error]; mov (%2), %%r5"
            : /* No outputs. */
            : "r"(x), "r"(&y)
            : "r5", "memory" 
            : error);
  return y;
error:
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: You have a leading space in `[ stop]`. Remove that. Also I suspect you did not actually use the code posted because the error should of course complain about `stop` and not `end`.

Comment: Wow I didn't know spaces count in this instruction ! Thank you very much ! It worked